# Mysql connection- check manual that correspond to your mysql server version

Tags: java, mysql, logging, sql-update

package com.example.dev1.controller;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
/*import java.sql.ResultSet;*/
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class ReadLg extends JApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String[] lev_param = {"DEBUG", "WARN", "INFO", "ERROR"};

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        /* ResultSet rs = null; */

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("All.log"));
            String username = "*****";
            String pwd = "*****";
            String connurl = "jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/d_accesslog?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connurl, username, pwd);

            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(line + "\t");
                String sql = "INSERT INTO t_weblogic_test (RawData) values ('"+line+"')";

                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }

            br.close();
            con.close();
            ps.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is I want to try reading and insert my log file to database and I got this error. can someone help me figure out this problem? At first, the program work as expected but suddenly it stopped. I want to insert my log file item to DB.

**This is the error**

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '2c9dc30c6ac6b815016b0452ce6341f0', ipAddress='202.184.57.105',
>   loginDate=2019-05' at line 1  at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1340)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
>     at com.example.dev1.controller.ReadLg.main(ReadLg.java:42)

The link below is my db structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhWQH.png

Comment: Your image is not loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your log have some text like that ipAddress='202.184.57.105', I think this problem is due to that type of string. you can write sql like this
 String sql = "INSERT INTO t_weblogic_test (RawData) values (\""+line+"\")";

to try again